# Is it possible to get a backup of firefox addons?

Tags: firefox, backup, browser-addons

I know we can backup bookmarks in firefox and restore it... Is there a similar process for addons installed in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FEBE (Firefox Environment Backup Extension)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109?src=api) allows you to quickly and easily backup your Firefox extensions. In fact, it goes beyond just backing up -- It will actually rebuild your extensions individually into installable .xpi files. Now you can easily synchronize your office and home browsers.

*p.s. works beautifully*

Comment: This extension is not available anymore.

Answer (score 2):

[MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com) allows you to backup and restore bookmarks, mail, contacts, history, extensions, cache, addons etc.

**It allows you the flexibility to choose what part of your profile you want to save**

[image: parameters to backup]

**It lets you backup and restore entire profiles that way you can backup and restore multiple FireFox profiles**

[image: profile backup and restore]

It is compatible with

- Firefox 1.0 - 3.6
- Thunderbird 1.0 -3.0
- Sunbird 0.3 - 0.9
- Flock 1.0 - 2.0
- Postbox 1.0 - 1.1
- SeaMonkey 1.0a -2.0
- Mozilla Suite 1.7 - 1.7.x
- Spicebird 0.4 - 0.8
- Songbird 1.0
- Netscape 7.x, 9.x
- Wyzo

[image: backup and restore profile]

Answer (score 2):

Or...in Windows, you can just go to `%appdata%\mozilla\firefox\profiles\[your default profile]\` and copy the extensions directory to a removable drive or other backup location. However, this probably will not save your extension(s)' data (things like session histories, etc.).

I just recommend backing up the contents of your `%appdata%\mozilla\firefox and %userprofile%\local settings\application data\mozilla\firefox` directories (in XP; this is slightly different for Vista/7); this step provides a full backup of the entirety of your firefox settings, history, bookmarks and extensions; if you wanted or needed, you could even transfer this backup to a freshly installed system or a different Windows computer altogether, although this *may* cause errors...

See [Moving your profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder) for more; this is an excellent article for *anyone* who wants to backup or move their Firefox profile.

As for non-windows systems such as Linux, I suspect that the directory layout structure might be similar, even though the default parent directory location would be (obviously) different (for instance, `~/.mozilla/firefox`). I have not tried, but it is possible to transfer your Firefox settings and data from a Windows computer to a non-Windows one (or vice-versa); see [Moving from Windows to Linux](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_from_Windows_to_Linux) for more.