# How do I backup Firefox add-on like "Fastdial" addon for a reinstall?

Tags: firefox, backup, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

I am doing a new install of Firefox and over the years my Windows "roaming folder" I use for backup has gotten all clogged up from so many add-ons and crap...
  I want to backup just a couple Firefox add-on's, one is "Fast dial" How do I backup this add-on and its addresses for when I reinstall Firefox and the add-on, so It will go back to where it is now?

Most add-on's have a backup feature like "too many tabs" bookmarks and such but fast dial doesn't? so How do I backup this add-on?

and /or addons like it without a backup feature?
Thanks in advance any help or options would be a big help.
Dana

Comment: Some add-ons's configuration files are stored in about:config. If you copy those and restore them you should be able to restore some settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get a backup of firefox addons?](https://superuser.com/questions/114206/is-it-possible-to-get-a-backup-of-firefox-addons)

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the `prefs.js` file from your profile folder.  That contains nearly all of the options and settings from Firefox and all your extensions.  Use it as a reference when reconfiguring your new profile, if you don't want to import it wholesale.

Some extensions store some of their data externally though.  Examples being Adblock Plus's blocklists, Stylish's UserStyles, Scriptish's UserScripts, etc.

The safest thing to do is backup your entire profile.  That way if you can't find or remember something, you can dig around in your backup until you find it.

Answer (score 1):

Use FEBE (a Firefox addon) for backup settings, profile, pref... anything you want.

http://softwarebychuck.com/febe/febe.html

EDIT: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/febe/

Comment: not on official ff add ons site?

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/febe/

Answer (score 0):

Fast Dial stores everything with the bookmarks folder so if you're doing *any* sort of bookmark synching you get it replicated to your other machines/browsers. I use Xmarks but there are certainly tons of other options including the native Mozilla one that's part of FF 4.

I use my Fast Dial bookmarks in Chrome, for instance. Not quite the same experience but still convenient.

Option B just occurred to me while writing the above.

In firefox go to Bookmarks -> Organize Bookmarks. You'll see the Fast Dial folder in the list. Right-click on it and choose "Export" to save your current 'marks.

Comment: Oh what about the actual settings you are using for fastdial arm will I just have to redo it when I reinstall?                                                             Oh Thank you, I forgot all fastdail links were saved in the bookmark page, so I really don't have to back up anything except my Bookmarks?

Comment: I don't know about the Fast Dial settings, but the core part is those bookmarks and they're easily saved. I tend to run Fast Dial with default settings so I haven't worried much about them, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah see I changed the Defult settings to fit more links on one view page so mine is like 10x6 squares to make it fit perfect in on my screen in my browser

Comment: Anyone else know anything about this, How I can backup the settings if you change it from Defult