# How to see a list of all installed Firefox extensions and export it?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I was wondering if there is a functionality or maybe another addon for Firefox were I can export all my addons into a simple list - preferably txt or html. I mean only the names because I start to lose track and want the same addons at home and work.

Comment: You can sync your addons so that they are automatically kept the same on different profiles, some addons can sync the settings too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get a backup of firefox addons?](https://superuser.com/questions/114206/is-it-possible-to-get-a-backup-of-firefox-addons)

Comment: note that you need to see `about:support` to get a complete list of extensions in firefox. If you only use `about:addons`, it will skip some (eg wikipedia, bing, amazon, etc) https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1267206

Comment: On my windows PC, I found my list of firefox extension file (.xpi) in C:\Users\myUserID\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\random profile name\extensions\

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<del>[Extension List Dumper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extension-list-dumper/) is an addon that can save your addons and themes as a file.</del>

**Edit:** As of Firefox 30, the above addon no longer works. You can get a list of all installed addons and other information about your Firefox installation by entering `about:support` in the URL bar. You can also try [Addon List Dumper (restartless)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/addon-list-dumper-restartless/) instead if you want to easily export a list.

Comment: Addon List Dumper (restartless) is great...not exactly what I wanted but close enough for me to work with it for my needs.

Comment: Neither of these add-ons are available any longer. The boilerplate page that they show is intentional, as discussed at https://github.com/mozilla/addons-frontend/issues/7129#issuecomment-460018995

Answer (score 5):

If you want to automate this, here's a Python script that prints the names of the installed addons, including an enabled flag. It accepts a single argument, the Firefox profile path, which can be found in the about:support page.

```
import json, os, sys
PROFILE, = sys.argv[1:]
path = os.path.join(PROFILE, 'extensions.json')
data = json.load(open(path, encoding='utf-8'))
for addon in data['addons']:
    enabled = '*' if addon['active'] else ' '
    name = addon['defaultLocale']['name']
    print(enabled, name)
```

Answer (score 4):

As none of the extensions are able to do this/Available in Firefox 85, here is an extension called "Nightly Tester Tools" that can be used to copy the list of addons: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nightly-tester-tools/

Answer (score 0):

0. Save about:addons as a complete HTML file, and
1. Use something like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/nimbus-screenshot/?utm_content=addons-manager-reviews-link&utm_medium=firefox-browser&utm_source=firefox-browser to capture the entirety of the page

   [image]

to produce

[image: Example]